# How can I reload the datastore and refresh a listview?

Tags: extjs, adobe, aem

I am struggling with a weird problem, and I can't make it work. Any help is appreciated.

I want to create a component dialog tab which has a panel, and this panel should show a listview which is getting it's content from a Servlet in JSON format.

The listview should be updated every time the user activates the dialog tab. Now, what I could achieve is that the JSON response is returned from the Servlet, but I cannot make the listview updated.

Dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    helpPath="en/cq/current/wcm/default_components.html#Slideshow"
    xtype="tabpanel">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <imageGallery
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            title="Image Gallery"
            xtype="panel">
            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <imageSource
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    fieldLabel="Image Source"
                    name="./source"
                    type="radio"
                    value="manual"
                    xtype="selection">
                    <listeners
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        loadcontent="function(field) {ImageGallery.radioSelection(field);}"
                        selectionchanged="function(field) {ImageGallery.radioSelection(field);}"/>
                    <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                        <option1
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            text="Read images from DAM folder"
                            value="dam"/>
                        <option2
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            text="Set images manually"
                            value="manual"/>
                    </options>
                </imageSource>
                <dam
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    collapsed="{Boolean}false"
                    title="Dam Folder"
                    xtype="dialogfieldset">
                    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                        <damFolder
                            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                            allowBlank="{Boolean}true"
                            fieldLabel="Dam Folder"
                            name="./dam/damfolderPath"
                            predicate="folder"
                            rootPath="/content/dam"
                            xtype="pathfield"/>
                        <damDescription
                            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                            fieldLabel=""
                            name="./dam/damDescription"
                            type="checkbox"
                            xtype="selection">
                            <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                <desc
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    text="Display description from DAM"
                                    value="true"/>
                            </options>
                        </damDescription>
                        <damFolderOptions
                            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                            fieldLabel=""
                            name="./dam/damfolderOptions"
                            type="checkbox"
                            xtype="selection">
                            <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                <subfolders
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    text="Include subfolder(s)"
                                    value="true"/>
                            </options>
                        </damFolderOptions>
                    </items>
                </dam>
                <slide
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    collapsed="{Boolean}false"
                    title="Manual Images"
                    xtype="dialogfieldset">
                    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                        <slides
                            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                            ddGroups="[media]"
                            fileReferencePrefix="./image$"
                            height="200"
                            hideLabel="{Boolean}true"
                            title="Slides"
                            xtype="slideshow"/>
                    </items>
                </slide>
                <show
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    ignoreData="{Boolean}true"
                    name="./show/sling:resourceType"
                    value="ubs/fit/base/components/image"
                    xtype="hidden"/>
            </items>
        </imageGallery>
        <tab2
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            path="/blah/blah/includes/dialog_tab_channels.infinity.json"
            xtype="cqinclude"/>
        <tab3
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            path="/blah/blah/includes/dialog_tab_reference.infinity.json"
            xtype="cqinclude"/>
        <order
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            title="Order"
            layout="hbox"
            pack="center"
            border="false"
            xtype="panel">
            <listeners
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                activate="function(panel) { var dialog = this.findParentByType('dialog'); ImageGallery.loadContent(panel, dialog); }"/>
        </order>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

Javascript:

```
ImageGallery = function() {

    var readerConfig = {
            idProperty: 'url',
            root: 'images',
            fields: [{name:'title', type: 'string', mapping: 'title'}]
    };

    var selectionChangedHandler = function(view, nodes){
        var l = nodes.length;
        var s = l != 1 ? 's' : '';
        var panel = view.findParentByType("panel");
        panel.setTitle('Simple ListView ('+l+' item'+s+' selected)');
        arrowUp.items.node = nodes[0];
        arrowDown.items.node = nodes[0];
        var records = this.getSelectedRecords();
        arrowUp.items.record = records[0];
        arrowDown.items.record = records[0];
    };

    var dataStoreLoaded = function(store, records, options) {
        listView.show();
    };

    var dataStore = new CQ.Ext.data.Store({
        reader: new CQ.Ext.data.JsonReader(readerConfig)
    });
    dataStore.on('load', dataStoreLoaded);

    var items = new Array();
    var listView = new CQ.Ext.list.ListView({
        fieldLabel: 'Change order of images',
        store: dataStore,
        autoShow: true,
        autoRender: true,
        multiSelect: false,
        singleSelect: true,
        emptyText: 'No images to display',
        reserveScrollOffset: true,
        flex: 80,
        autoScroll: true,
        columns: [{
            header: 'File',
            width: .5,
            dataIndex: 'title',
            tpl: '{title}'
        }],
    });
    listView.on('selectionchange', selectionChangedHandler);
    items.push(listView);

    var arrowUp = {
            "xtype": "panel",
            "border": false,
            "layout": "hbox",
            "pack": "center",
            "flex": 10,
            "items": {
                "xtype": "button",
                "iconCls": "cq-multifield-up",
                "template": new CQ.Ext.Template('<span><button class="x-btn" type="{0}"></button></span>'),
                "handler": function(){
                    var results = CQ.Util.eval(CQ.shared.HTTP.post(
                            '/blah/blah/imageGallery',
                            function(options, success, xhr, response) {
                                alert('Arrowup callback called');
                            },
                            { baseUrl: "", fileReference: "", title: "", slideIndex: 11, command: "moveUp" }));
                },
                "node": undefined,
                "record": undefined
            }
    };
    items.push(arrowUp);

    var arrowDown = {
            "xtype": "panel",
            "border": false,
            "layout": "hbox",
            "pack": "center",
            "flex": 10,
            "items": {
                "xtype": "button",
                "iconCls": "cq-multifield-down",
                "template": new CQ.Ext.Template('<span><button class="x-btn" type="{0}"></button></span>'),
                "handler": function(){
                    var results = CQ.Util.eval(CQ.shared.HTTP.post(
                            '/blah/blah/imageGallery',
                            function(options, success, xhr, response) {
                                alert('Arrowdown callback called');
                            },
                            { baseUrl: "", fileReference: "", title: "", slideIndex: 11, command: "moveDown" }));
                },
                "node": undefined,
                "record": undefined
            }
    };
    items.push(arrowDown);

    return {
        loadContent : function(panel, dialog) {
            try {
                var baseUrl = dialog.path;
                var dataSrcUrl = '/blah/blah/imageGallery?baseURL=' + baseUrl;
                var proxy = new CQ.Ext.data.HttpProxy( { url: dataSrcUrl } );
                panel.add(items);
                dataStore.proxy = proxy;
                dataStore.load();
            } catch(err) {
                alert(err);
            };
        }

    };

}();
```

JSON response:

```
{
  "images": [
    {
      "url": "/content/dam/ubs/homepage/sections/section_06_b.png",
      "title": "Tablet",
      "dam": {
        "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
        "jcr:created": "Fri Mar 21 2014 15:24:19 GMT+0100",
        "jcr:primaryType": "dam:Asset",
        "jcr:content": {
          "jcr:lastModifiedBy": "t425199",
          "pageid": "c7e916d4-0a57-4cd3-8e58-b2f077a5c2fa",
          "cq:lastModified": "Wed Mar 19 2014 14:48:27 GMT+0100",
          "jcr:lastModified": "Fri Mar 21 2014 15:24:45 GMT+0100",
          "jcr:primaryType": "dam:AssetContent",
          "cq:lastModifiedBy": "t136233",
          "metadata": {
            "dc:format": "image/png",
            "dam:size": 98446,
            "dam:Physicalwidthininches": 4.943826675415039,
            "jcr:mixinTypes": [
              "cq:Taggable"
            ],
            "tiff:ImageLength": 124,
            "dam:favorite": ";admin;",
            "dam:sha1": "b825986808be89ec7d974b0fbc2bd0dfed9bb83b",
            "dam:extracted": "Fri Mar 21 2014 15:24:45 GMT+0100",
            "dam:MIMEtype": "image/png",
            "dam:Numberoftextualcomments": 0,
            "dam:Numberofimages": 1,
            "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured",
            "dam:Progressive": "no",
            "dam:Fileformat": "PNG",
            "dam:Bitsperpixel": 32,
            "dam:Physicalheightininches": 1.722006916999817,
            "dam:Physicalheightindpi": 72,
            "dam:Physicalwidthindpi": 72,
            "tiff:ImageWidth": 356
          },
          "related": {
            "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured"
          },
          "renditions": {
            "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
            "jcr:created": "Fri Mar 21 2014 15:24:19 GMT+0100",
            "jcr:primaryType": "nt:folder",
            "original": {
              "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
              "jcr:created": "Fri Mar 21 2014 15:24:19 GMT+0100",
              "jcr:primaryType": "nt:file",
              "jcr:content": {
                "jcr:lastModifiedBy": "t425199",
                "jcr:mimeType": "image/png",
                "jcr:uuid": "edf89bdd-acb3-4de7-8595-cc42407bc6b4",
                "jcr:lastModified": "Fri Mar 21 2014 15:24:19 GMT+0100",
                "jcr:primaryType": "nt:resource",
                ":jcr:data": 98446
              }
            },
            "cq5dam.thumbnail.319.319.png": {
              "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
              "jcr:created": "Fri Mar 21 2014 15:24:45 GMT+0100",
              "jcr:primaryType": "nt:file",
              "jcr:content": {
                "jcr:lastModifiedBy": "admin",
                "jcr:mimeType": "image/png",
                "jcr:uuid": "abd698c0-c869-40a9-92de-53b7e9773574",
                "jcr:lastModified": "Fri Mar 21 2014 15:24:45 GMT+0100",
                "jcr:primaryType": "nt:resource",
                ":jcr:data": 94018
              }
            },
            "cq5dam.thumbnail.140.100.png": {
              "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
              "jcr:created": "Fri Mar 21 2014 15:24:45 GMT+0100",
              "jcr:primaryType": "nt:file",
              "jcr:content": {
                "jcr:lastModifiedBy": "admin",
                "jcr:mimeType": "image/png",
                "jcr:uuid": "6180db61-775c-466b-b07f-1246e47ab08d",
                "jcr:lastModified": "Fri Mar 21 2014 15:24:45 GMT+0100",
                "jcr:primaryType": "nt:resource",
                ":jcr:data": 18872
              }
            },
            "cq5dam.thumbnail.48.48.png": {
              "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
              "jcr:created": "Fri Mar 21 2014 15:24:45 GMT+0100",
              "jcr:primaryType": "nt:file",
              "jcr:content": {
                "jcr:lastModifiedBy": "admin",
                "jcr:mimeType": "image/png",
                "jcr:uuid": "1c8232ee-9e75-4f97-8dad-5f7dc729480b",
                "jcr:lastModified": "Fri Mar 21 2014 15:24:45 GMT+0100",
                "jcr:primaryType": "nt:resource",
                ":jcr:data": 2529
              }
            },
            "cq5dam.web.1280.1280.png": {
              "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
              "jcr:created": "Fri Mar 21 2014 15:24:50 GMT+0100",
              "jcr:primaryType": "nt:file",
              "jcr:content": {
                "jcr:lastModifiedBy": "admin",
                "jcr:mimeType": "image/png",
                "jcr:uuid": "b046053a-9329-48db-bd86-5ea998926d1c",
                "jcr:lastModified": "Fri Mar 21 2014 15:24:50 GMT+0100",
                "jcr:primaryType": "nt:resource",
                ":jcr:data": 117473
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "url": "/content/dam/ubs/homepage/sections/ch/ch_engagement_img_leichtathletik.jpg",
      "title": "Girls",
      "dam": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

So, when I open the dialog and click on the 'Order' tab, then the list view header and the arrow buttons are displayed, but the list view has no content. How can I reload the datastore and display the JSON response in the list view in this case?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a `CQ.Ext.list.ListView`, but from the [ListView API](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/widgets-api/), it looks like you can use the method `refresh`.

Comment: @incutonez Thanks for the reply, I tried it, but no change. The list is empty. Actually, it's kind of strange, but the 'No images to display' text is also missing.

Comment: Not sure the problem in too detail but if you want to reload the dataStore, that will give view updated data from the json, to relaod store use listView.getStore().reload([options]) method in the same documentation which @incutonez has mentioned. Hope this helps.